# Can two ListViews use the same ArrayAdapter?

Tags: android

As far as I know, ArrayAdapter is used to handle data for ListView's content. I have two ListViews (in the same activity) that contain the same data, **with two different behaviors (should be handle in two different onListItemClick() )** though. Can I use the same ArrayAdapter for both of them? I can check this but I'm not sure it will create bug if I use the same Adapter.

Furthermore,if I don't extend ListActivity as in this [tutorial](http://www.vogella.de/articles/AndroidListView/article.html), how can I handle onListItemClick() events from those ListViews?

Thank in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can use the same Adapter. And you can handle clicks by implementing `.setOnItemClickListener()` for listView1 and listView2.

Answer (score 1):

I haven't tried it, but as long as you instantiate two different adapters I guess you can use the same class for both listviews.

As for your last question, you can:

a) set onItemClickedListener for both listViews

b) set an onClickListener to the convertView inside getView() and you should be able to handle the events as with any normal listener.